# Placing an ImageView in a special position

Tags: android, layout, position, imageview

This problem might seem very basic but I couldn't find an answer to it.

I need to place an imageView in a special position in the screen. Suppose, I need it to be three tenth from the top, and one fifth from the left of the screen.

The first thing that comes to mind is to use an AbsoluteLayout and place the imageView using absolute coordinates. However this method causes problems in working with different screen sizes. The problem is that I can not get the screen dimensions (width and height) in the xml file, and on the other hand, I couldn't find a setX() / setY() or similar method for ImageView to do it programatically.

An idea to solve this problem was using LinearLayout instead of AbsoluteLayout and to insert dummy views (like textVies) to fill the space behind or above my desired imageView. But this gets complicated if I have multiple imageViews to place in the screen and if the desired positions are not aligned. Another solution was using padding or margin, but it didn't work with the AbsoluteView.

I don't need the imageView to be in a relative position with some other view, I just need it to be in a special position in the screen.

Comment: If you are deadest on using percentages of screen size for placement LinearLayout with `android:layout_weight` is the only way to do so AFAIK. However you could use a RelativeLayout and specify your margins with dp units which will scale them to different densities, but I don't think it would keep the integrity of your percentage

Answer (score 0):

Although it said that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, but this code worked for me:

```
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp=new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,x,y);
    myImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: this code worked for me: => FYI, it looks fine for 1-2 device but it would get shrinked/stretched on other devices.